# How to load an UrlResource with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to load a HTTP zip file with `UrlResource`:

```
new UrlResource("url:http://www.my-path.to/file.zip")
```

Result.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL
>   [http://www.my-path.to/file.zip] cannot be resolved to absolute file
>   path because it does not reside in the file system.

What is the correct way of loading a HTTP file with the `Resource` interface?

I later on want to add that Resource to an `ItemReader` for Spring Batch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `http:` prefix instead of `url:` to reference a HTTP resource with [`UrlResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html).

Quoting from [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations-urlresource):

> All URLs have a standardized `String` representation, such that appropriate standardized prefixes are used to indicate one URL type from another. This includes `file:` for accessing filesystem paths, **`http:` for accessing resources via the HTTP protocol**, `ftp:` for accessing resources via FTP, etc.

As such, you would just have `new UrlResource("http://www.my-path.to/file.zip")`.